# Open a view programmatically with tab controller from storyboard

Tags: ios

I have a storyboard which has following views (scenes):

- Login screen
- TabBarController with 4 tabs ( Library, Workflow, Settings & downloads

Based on user login by clicking on the button (Sign in), I programatically load tab bar controller with always first tab with following code:

```
         LibraryWebViewContoller *lbc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"docovaMainTabBarController"];
         [self presentViewController:lbc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What I want do is be able to open different tabs programmatically with TabBarController from storyboard. So far I am able to open the tab bar controller with first tab but no luck in opening others as it always seem to load the TabBarController with first tab selected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using following code:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"docovaMainTabBarController"];
tbc.selectedIndex=1;
[self presentViewController:tbc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, remember to edit the storyboard and give the UITabBarController a storyboard ID set to docovaMainTabBarController so it can be uniquely identified within the storyboard.

### Swift

```
  let tbc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"docovaMainTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
   tbc.selectedIndex = 1
   self.present(tbc, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Maybe good to mention that the first tab has index 0. But kind of a no brainer for programmers.

Comment: This one does not work for me I had to attach a navigation controller on the tabViewController then instantiate like that above but call the navigationController instead of the tab bar

Answer (score 1):

Say you wanted to have the second view controller selected. Set the activeViewController property on the tab bar controller)

```
lbc.activeViewController = [lbv.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

(not sure of lbc is the tab bar controller or the first view controller in the tab bar - assuming it is)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. You got me pointed in the right direction. Here is the code I used to achieve:             UITabBarController *tbc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"docovaMainTabBarController"];
             tbc.selectedIndex=1;
             [self presentViewController:tbc animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Swift4:

`let tbc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "docovaMainTabBarController") as? UITabBarController
tbc.selectedIndex = 1
present(tbc, animated: true) {() -> Void in }`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBarController", bundle: .main)
let tabbarController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
tabbarController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(tabbarController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```