# Presenting TabBarController's second Tab from NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

I'm trying when I successfully pass from entry viewController (LoginViewController), the Tab Bar open the second tab item. I know how to do it if the Tab Bar was the entry point of the app, with this code in appDelegate.m file:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[tabBar setSelectedIndex:1];
```

but this doesn't help me a lot this time.

I start thinking maybe a solution is to create a custom class for Tab Bar Controller but I m not sure how to do it.

Right now when the user successfully login in, this line of code controllers the segue between LoginViewController(button) and TabBarController.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginToTabBarSegue" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127711/open-a-view-programatically-with-tab-controller-from-storyboard/19135247#19135247) on stackoverflow by DP2 which is the solution of my problem.

This is the line of the code I put in login button when the user successfully login in.

```
UITabBarController *loadTabBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarViewControllerID"];
loadTabBar.selectedIndex=1;
[self presentViewController:loadTabBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the tab bar:

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[nav.topViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Didn't work, It's starting without errors, but it's still loading the first tab after login. I'm continue searching the solution...

Answer (score 0):

You're using UITabBarController incorrectly. A tab bar controller should never be embedded into a navigation controller. From Apple's docs:

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It seems like you want a user to log in before they can use your app. And that the tab bar controller contains the bulk of your app's UI. Consider setting the Tab bar controller as the root view controller of your app and then having the user log in through a modally presented LoginViewController.