# How can we open the tab bar first VC on click in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have a VC which on click of button want to open the tabbar VC that is on the first index. I wana open this through present style. My home vc is on the tab bar first index. How can i open that?. My UI looks like that,
[image]

The code i tried is this,

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
                if let vcs = tabbarVC.viewControllers,
                    let nc = vcs.first as? UINavigationController,

                self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a view programatically with tab controller from storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127711/open-a-view-programatically-with-tab-controller-from-storyboard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can give an id and open directly

```
let first = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstID") 
self.present(first , animated: false, completion: nil)
```

//

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
 self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Bro when i try this code it open the VC but does not show the tab bar under, it has hide my tab bar. @Sh_Khan

Comment: where you want to present it from ??  what index you want the tabbar to be initially opened ??

Comment: in my screenshot u can see that , i have a simple VC having navigation controller attach to it. I want to go from this VC to the tab bar  and it should open the first index VC in tab bar. @Sh_Khan

Comment: no same issue again it is not showing tab bar at the bottom. @Sh_Khan

Comment: we have to make the path via tab bar u r opening it directly by identifier. @Sh_Khan

Comment: MainVC is the id of the tabbar ?? it should load it

Comment: no it is the id of first VC of tab bar, i haven't given any identifier of tab bar and no class is attach to tab bar controller. @Sh_Khan

Comment: give it identifier and load